# New Pokemon bonus with Lucky Egg

Tags: pokemon-go

I can't seem to find the answer to this:

Will the New Pokemon bonus of 500XP double with the Lucky Egg's double XP effect?

I'm saving my evolutions for my Lucky Egg and I know I'll be evolving some Pokemon into ones I haven't before (thus the bonus).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Yes.**

The Lucky Egg bonus does increase the +500xp new Pokémon bonus. I've been saving my eggs until I can get about 2-3 new evolutions in addition to my stock Weedle and Pidgey evolution sprees.

Comment: Take into accoutn that you'll loose some time for the new Pokémon to be registered into the Pokédex

Comment: @Anzeo You lose about 6 seconds due to the registering effect but gain double the exp as a repeat evolution would. I'd think that a spree of only "new" pokemon would provide more experience even though you wouldn't have time for as many evolutions.

Comment: @Kadima not true, both evolution and new Pokédex entry provide the same amount of XP by default (500). I don't know if the timings differ so if a new registration would take less than an evolution it would in fact make sense to try to maximize these while under the effect of a Lucky Egg. I don't know these exact timings, but was just pointing out that if you'd used i.e. PidgeyCalc to maximize the effect of a Lucky Egg it does not take new registrations into account.

Comment: @Anzeo I'm sorry if I didn't explain myself well, but you just said "not true" to my statement and then agreed with me. Evolution animations take about 20-25 seconds, the exact number is somewhere on this site. Registering a new pokemon takes less than 10 seconds. Since they both provide 500xp, evolutions with new pokemon take longer but are technically more "exp dense" over an equalized time period of multiple evolutions, due to the fact that a single evolution with the new pokemon effect gives the same exp as two evolutions without the new pokemon effect.

Comment: @Kadima I was referring to your statement that you would "gain double the exp as a repeat evolution would". Sorry if I misunderstood it.

Comment: @Anzeo Ah, okay. But it does gain double, because you gain 500xp for the evolution and 500xp for the new pokemon being registered, so you get 1000xp total from evolving a single pokemon.

Comment: ...and then of course doubles on a Lucky Egg. So an evolution, into a new Pokemon, while using a Lucky Egg, will net you 2000xp

Comment: @TimMalone That's why I save up a couple of new evolutions :) The boost in exp compliments the egg really nicely at higher levels (provided you aren't running out of new evolves)